# Why is Ubuntu running relatively slowly on my machine?

Tags: ssd, intel, mint, sshd

So I run my Desktop with a dual boot of Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19.4, my desktop specs are:

- Motherboard: MSI X570 Gaming Carbon Pro Wifi
- System HD for Win10: Sabrent 4 1TB NvME SSD
- System HD for Mint: Samsung 840 SATA 3 SSD
- MSI Radeon 5700XT
- AMD Ryzen 3800
- 64GB of RAM

Both windows and Mint fly on this system, but Mint is significantly quicker than Windows.

On my Laptop I'm also running a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10, my laptop specs are:

- MSI GL72 7RS Laptop
- Windows on a Samsung 870 NvME SSD
- Ubuntu on a Seagate Hybrid SATA 3 SSHD
- 7th Gen Intel i7
- 32GB of RAM
- Nvidia GTX 1050 video card

I am certainly not expecting Ubuntu to run as fast on my Laptop as Mint does on my Desktop. But Windows 10 does run HEAPS faster than Ubuntu does, like waaay faster. Boots faster, I can open software faster, everything goes much faster.

I know the NvME SSD will provide a boost to Win10 over the SSHD Ubuntu is installed on, but I also figured that Ubuntu would be lighter than Mint, and Ubuntu would, at the very least, be as fast Windows.

On my big system Win is installed on on a NvME drive, and Mint used to be installed there as well, but I did clone Mint to an older SATA III SSD in the Evo840 so there's that bit of a handicap.

Should I pick up an SATA III SSD for my laptop and reinstall and see how it goes?

I just figured Ubuntu would perform as well as windows on my system, but it is comparatively sloooow.

FWIW - the latest iso of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS would simply not stay booted from the Live USB, so that's why I opted for 19.10.

Comment: Which nvidia driver are you using? The open-source one is usually slower. Try installing the proprietary one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: It's possible that your CPU might be stuck in a lower power state (or not turbo boosting). You should run a CPU intensive task, (i.e. rendering something in Blender) and compare performance between Windows and Linux.

Comment: Turns out the difference between the SSD and SSHD was indeed a huge factor. I decided to blow up both my laptop and my desktop and start from scratch. Installed both mint and ubuntu on both systems and both on SSDs. Performance between the two was essentially the same. Mint being slightly smoother.